# How do I add sizing options to products in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

I'm about to build an online store in Ruby on Rails using Spree.  So far I don't see how I can add sizes to items, such as T-shirts.  I don't want to have to create multiple version of the same product just to have the size represented.  Does anyone know how to do this or if its' even possible?

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: actually I'm in research mode right now so I haven't done anything, I'm just trying to make sure there's a way to do it before I begin.  I know it's a standard here to not just ask people to do stuff without any effort, but I honestly don't know if it can be done or how to even try.  I have found a couple things talking about "variants" that can add options but haven't seen anything showing how they function or how to set them up.

Comment: Yes it's possible by using variants :-) Sandbox is no longer available on Spree site so if I were you I would install Spree locally and see how does variants fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you create variants of products.

First understand

Product Variants: Sometimes the same product is available in different styles or types. For example, you might sell a t-shirt in a number of different sizes, or a hat in a variety of different colors. Create product variants to show your customers all the options they can choose from.

Opiton Types and Values in spree: Option Types are a way to help distinguish products in your store from one another. They are particularly useful when you have many products that are basically of the same general category (Tshirts or mugs, for example), but with characteristics that can vary, such as color, size, or logo.
Read more at: https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/product_options.html

Then, create Option Type size with option values as the size values. Option Type is avaliable under Product's sub-menu. 
Next create new variants of the product with the given values in the admin panel. Select the product from the products list in admin. Then go to Variants on the right Sub-menu.

This should solve your problem. For details refer to https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/products.html

Answer (score 0):

Another good note - you can create Prototypes. A prototype consists of one or more option types. Option types can be size and color. Combined these become a prototype.

When a new product is created, use the prototype to generate all the variants for a product. All options of color and size from each option type will be generated.

The show product page will need to have ability to filter on size and color to get to the required variant.

If you integrate with external systems then make sure to set the SKU on each variant line.